# Java post increment vs opcode iinc

Tags: java, bytecode, post-increment

Most of us are familiar with post increment, but when I look to the bytecode instructions, it shows the increment happened before the invocation to the method.

Example:

```
int x = 0;
aMethod(x++);
```

bytecode:

```
0: iconst_0
1: istore_1
2: iload_1
3: iinc          1, 1
6: invokestatic  #2                  // Method aMethod:(I)V
9: return
```

Can someone clarify this?

Comment: Yes, but what value was passed to `aMethod`? 0.

Comment: iinc doesn't change the stack and you've pushed the value of your variable on the stack before you updated it with iinc.

Comment: @president-james-k-polk: It doesn't matter, the question about post increment vs iinc instruction

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk actually helps my to understand a little bit this... because the post increment works as expected and another thing (but related) is how javac generates bytecodes.. my upvote for both of you, is really interesting! it would be more intereseting to see `anotherMethod(x++,x++);` because on that case, the first evaluated argument should be 0 and the other should be 1.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @voo

I've made a another example for pre increment for comparison purpose:

```
0: iconst_0
1: istore_1
2: iinc          1, 1
5: iload_1
6: invokestatic  #2                  // Method aMethod:(I)V
9: return
```

The difference can be seen in instruction 2# and 5# (iinc invoked before iload_1), while in in post increment, iload_1 invoked before iinc.

That means the increment will occur on the variable itself and not on the copy pushed onto the stack, which been used as parameter to invoke the method.

from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html):

> iinc
>
> Increment local variable by constant
>
> The index is an unsigned byte **that must be an index into the local
> variable array of the current frame** (§2.6). The const is an immediate
> signed byte. The local variable at index must contain an int. The
> value const is first sign-extended to an int, and then the local
> variable at index is incremented by that amount.